# Why doesn't $@ work when passing strings?

Tags: bash

For example, using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in $@
do
   echo $a
done
```

And running:`./script "x y" z` returns:

```
x
y
z
```

and not:

```
x y
z
```

Why is that?
And how would I pass string arguments with spaces to bash?

I use `Bash 4.3.33`.

Comment: See the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) about this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quote `$@`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for a in "$@"
do
  echo "$a"
done
```

Output:

```
x y
z
```

Comment: For some versions (at least) of `bash`, it's enough to say `for a`. It will assume that you mean `in "$@"`.

Comment: On a side note, how does one do this with introducing a variable? For example `T=$@ for a in $T do echo "$a" done` does not work.

Comment: @orangeorange You can't safely store multiple arguments in a plain variable. But you can store them in an array with `t=("$@")`, and then reference it as `"${t[@]}"` to recover the original argument list intact. Note that *all* of the double-quotes I used are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in when dealing with `$@` you can simplify it to

```
for a
do
   echo "$a"
done
```

```
If `in WORDS ...;' is not present, then `in "$@"' is assumed.
```

Comment: See Scott's comment.